# How to fill each element of a 2d array with a for loop in python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

Whats happening is the loop is iterating and filling the elements of the array, but 'element wise' - ie it is calculating the first element correctly, then looping again and filling the first element again with what should be the second element....so ultimately, i have a 2d array/matrix filled with the values that should only be in the last element of my matrix. How to make it such that once the first element is filled, the for loop moves on to the next element and the next value?

Heres what Ive tried:

```
sim_matrix=np.zeros((3,3), dtype=float)

for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        for k in range(0,3):
            for l in range(0,3):
                    sim_matrix[i][j]=node_list_bsc[0][k]['bsc mean value']-node_list_bsc[1][l]['bsc mean value']

#node_list_bsc[x][y]['bsc mean value'] are float values - they are stored in a list of dictionaries,
#hence the double indexing
```

this gives:

```
array([[1.14488261e-08, 1.14488261e-08, 1.14488261e-08],
       [1.14488261e-08, 1.14488261e-08, 1.14488261e-08],
       [1.14488261e-08, 1.14488261e-08, 1.14488261e-08]])
```

but it should give:

```
[[-5.131371757023141e-10, -7.509188731093747e-08, 7.67647989217221e-07],
 [8.933230795306053e-08, 1.475355781782538e-08, 8.574934343459839e-07],
 [-7.567123003427902e-07, -8.312910504780254e-07, 1.144882605013307e-08]]
```

So as you can see, its filling up with the last element only. I ran the print command from within the centre of these nest for loops to see how it was filling, and its like this: (example)

```
[[-5.13137176e-10  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]]

[[-7.50918873e-08  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]]...
```

i.e. first element is correct but then gets replaced by 2nd element. This is probably obvious already from the code but I think its still useful to illustrate.
I've also tried with while loops, and if - else statements - something like:

```
#pseudo code following:
for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        for k in range(0,3):
            for l in range(0,3):
            if sim_matrix[i][j]==0.0:
                    sim_matrix[i][j]=node_list_bsc[0][k]['bsc mean value']-node_list_bsc[1][l]['bsc mean value']
            else: continue
```

It feels pretty close - but i just cant quite figure out where Im going wrong!

Comment: Please check your indentation on your inner most for loop.

Comment: It's not clear why you are running the two inner loops. `i` and `j` don't change during those loops so you set the same element (`sim_matrix[i][j]`) over and over.

Comment: Is your matrix large enough? I see you have it set to 3 x 3 but since there are 4 loops, shouldn't it be 4 x 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your problem, you are getting the same number in every place of your 2D array. At first, it is difficult to suggest anything without knowing about "node_list_bsc". However, to assign values to a 2D array you only need two loops. Your code can be written as
sim_matrix=np.zeros((3,3), dtype=float)

```
for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        if sim_matrix[i][j]==0.0:
            sim_matrix[i][j]=node_list_bsc[0][i]['bsc mean value']- node_list_bsc[1][j]['bsc mean value']
```

If it does not work, let me know and provide more information about node_list_bsc.